# Split every row in data frame and add value to each element avoiding NaN

Tags: python, pandas

the question originates from here: [Split every row in df and add value to each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972968/split-every-row-in-df-and-add-value-to-each-element)

here is updated df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_index': [3590,63, 15], 'movie_index': [1514,563, 9], 
'genre_index':['10|12|17|35', '4|2|1|8', None], 'cast_index':['46|534', None, '9|27']})
```

to get the desired dataframe in which to every element would be added a value, I try:

```
offset_dct = {'user_index': 2, 'genre_index': 5}
df.astype(str).fillna('').apply(lambda x: [
[int(z) + offset_dct.get(x.name, 0) for z in y.split('|') if z is not None else []] for y in x])
```

but it returns me an error:

```
ValueError: ("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'", 'occurred at index genre_index')
```

if there were no 'NaN', this code would work perfectly:

```
offset_dct = {'user_index': 2, 'genre_index': 5}
df = df.fillna('').astype(str).apply(lambda x: [
    [int(z) + offset_dct.get(x.name, 0) for z in y.split('|')] for y in x])
```

the problem is in constructing a list comprehension for ignoring NaN I think..

any help to solve would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the order of the `astype` and `fillna` calls.

```
>>> df.astype(str).fillna('')
user_index movie_index  genre_index cast_index
0       3590        1514  10|12|17|35     46|534
1         63         563      4|2|1|8       None
2         15           9         None       9|27
```

If you switch the order of the two methods you get something that works:

```
>>> df.fillna('').astype(str).apply(lambda x: [ [int(z) + offset_dct.get(x.name, 0) for z in y.split('|') if z] for y in x])
  user_index movie_index       genre_index cast_index
0     [3592]      [1514]  [15, 17, 22, 40]  [46, 534]
1       [65]       [563]     [9, 7, 6, 13]         []
2       [17]         [9]                []    [9, 27]
```

Also there was an error in your original list comprehension.  You can't put an else clause in the if condition of a list comprehension.  The if condition is purely there to tell the comprehension which values to keep.  If you wanted to do something differently depending on the value of each item, you'd need to put that logic in the function part of the comprehension (probably using a lambda expression).  But for this particular problem you didn't need anything else than what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

How about a two step approach?

1. Convert to list:

   ```
   df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if pd.isna(x) else str(x).split('|'))
   ```
2. Add:

   ```
   offset_dct = {'user_index': 2, 'genre_index': 5}
   for k,v in offset_dct.items():
       df[k] = df[k].map(lambda x: [int(i)+5 for i in x] if isinstance(x,list) else x)
   ```